# How to add Variable to Postman Sub folder

Tags: postman

I have following collection: 
[Student Service Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhG9F.png)

I want to have one environment for it with a set of default variables and then be able to re-write this values on sub-folder level. The reason for that is to not having like X-Auth-Dev, X-Auth-QA and X-Auth-Prod variable in the same env. Is there any normal way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [pre-request script at the folder-level](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/intro-to-scripts/#scripts-in-postman) to set the auth variable to the appropriate server environment credentials. A pre-request script at the folder-level will execute prior to every request in the folder.

Depending on how you run the collection, you may want to reset the default values at the end (if the values are persisted and you don't want them to be).

Comment: This is bad for creating API documentation in Postman because it won't replaces the variable on the documentation